# What’s the best way to reload / refresh multiple iframe/iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I wanted to reload/refresh iframe by using a loop because I have almost 300 iframes to reload/refresh

```
    function myFrame1() {
        var ifr = document.getElementsByName('frame1')[0];ifr.src = ifr.src;}
    function myFrame2() {
        var ifr =document.getElementsByName('frame2')[0];ifr.src = ifr.src;}
    function myFrame3() {
        var ifr =document.getElementsByName('frame3')[0];ifr.src = ifr.src;}
    function myFrame4() {
        var ifr =document.getElementsByName('frame4')[0];ifr.src = ifr.src;}
    function myFrame5() {
        var ifr =document.getElementsByName('frame5')[0];ifr.src = ifr.src;}
    function myFrame6() {
        var ifr =document.getElementsByName('frame6')[0];ifr.src = ifr.src;}
    function myFrame7() {
        var ifr =document.getElementsByName('frame7')[0];ifr.src = ifr.src;}
```

//continued for 300 iframes. This should work for this kind of frame

```
<iframe name="frame36" src="ima/P&ID/91-120002/91-120002-02/Grp_91-120002-02.htm" alt="" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: inline-block; height: 524px; width: 720px;" border="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why do you have 300 iframes on your page?!!

Comment: Use a loop - although as @NisargShah says, you really, ***really*** should not have 300 iframes on your page. There's no excuse for that

Comment: I was hoping that was a typo ... 30 ... still a lot, but 300!!!!

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way is to use querySelectorAll and forEach

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(ifr => ifr.src = ifr.src);
```

for old browser support

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('iframe'), function(ifr) { 
    ifr.src = ifr.src;
});
```

Comment: Not sure, but does `NodeList` has definition for `.forEach`? Probably try using `Array.from(...)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan [NodeList.forEach - Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). This is added recently and would fail for older browser

Comment: Well its an ES2015 feature, so no IE support is a given :)

Comment: Let me know how to use for this iframe
 
<iframe  src="ima/P&ID/91-120002/91-120002-02/Grp_91-120002-02.htm" alt="" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: inline-block; height: 524px; width: 720px;" border="0"></iframe>

Comment: for that iframe, I would use `document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(ifr => ifr.src = ifr.src);`

Comment: do use `<iframe>`, but don't use `<frame>` - or the 90's will call to demand their website back

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
```

or

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
```

or by name if you have multiple iframes

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('[name^=frame]');
```

then

```
for (i = 0 ; i < iframes.length ; i++){
      iframes[i].src = iframes[i].src;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that and with it can be very simple :

```
var iframe = $('iframe'), src;
iframe.each(function(index,element){
  src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

If you want to refresh you can use settimeout or setinterval (long polling)